# Understanding the conditions that would allow accused manslayer to return to his hometown (Joshua 20)

Tags: law, joshua

Joshua 20 deals with sanctuary cities for those who have unintentionally kills someone.  However, I'm trying to get a better understanding of what Joshua 20:6 is stating.

> NASB  Joshua 20:4-6
>
> 4 He shall flee to one of these cities, and shall stand at the
>   entrance of the gate of the city and state his case in the hearing of
>   the elders of that city; and they shall [d]take him into the city to
>   them and give him a place, so that he may dwell among them. 5 Now if
>   the avenger of blood pursues him, then they shall not deliver the
>   manslayer into his hand, because he struck his neighbor without
>   premeditation and did not hate him beforehand. **6 He shall dwell in that city 
>   until he stands before the congregation for judgment, until the death
>   of the one who is high priest in those days. Then the manslayer shall
>   [e]return to his own city and to his own house, to the city from which
>   he fled.’”**

A) Is Joshua 20:6 stating that the following 2 conditions have to be met in order for the guilty manslayer to return to his own home town?

- until he stands before the congregation for judgment
- until the death of the one who is high priest in those days

B) Also, I can understand that the manslayer needs to dwell in the sanctuary city until the congregation judges him, but I do Not understand why he would be free to return to his home town when the high priest at that particular point in time dies.  Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

I found some information on wikipedia. Reference is made to the *Mishnah* and *Talmud*, and that the High Priest's death was considered an atonement to that person who accidentally killed someone and was in the city of refuge.  See article [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cities_of_Refuge#cite_note-Makkot_11a-9).

It is wikipedia, so I'm not sure on the accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

This is a direct reference to the law established in Num 35:24, 25 about the length of stay and the two conditions under which such a person could be released.  The pulpit commentary observes (for Josh 20:6):

> Certainly the fact that the high priest died the common death of all
>   men, and the inauguration of his successor to fill his place could in
>   no way be regarded as an atonement for sin. There is more force in
>   Bahr's suggestion in his 'Symbolik' (2:52). The high priest, on this
>   view, is the head of the theocracy, the representative of the
>   covenant. He concentrates in his person (so Bahr puts it in another
>   place - see vol. 2:13) the whole people of Israel in their religious
>   aspect. His death, therefore, stands in a connection with the life of
>   Israel which that of no other man could do. "It is," says Maimonides
>   ('Moreh Nevochim,' 3.40), "the death of the most honoured and beloved
>   man in all Israel. His death plunges the whole community into such
>   distress that private sorrow is lost in the general affliction." Thus
>   the covenant in a way recommences with the inauguration of the new
>   high priest.